# How to integrate appery and pubnub

Tags: cordova, api, rest, pubnub

have you any pointers for me to get pubnub working on appery.io? I am quite a basic developer, but if you point me in the right direction, I will (eventually) get there. I basically want to build a app in appery.io using pubnub features. Do i need to download one of the sdks? If so which one, (or which ones are options) and how do i go about loading that sdk into appery.io.

Greatly appreciate any help you can give

Comment: Plese ask specific programming related questions.

Comment: like i said, i am new to this. Maybe this would be more specific. Pubnub offers 70+ sdks including angular js and cordova. If I download one these sdks can I then install it into appery.io environment to build app using pubnub features? If so how? Or do I use pubnub as a rest api from appery so the app makes requests to the api in order to use the functions? I hope that makes some sense

Comment: You need to read the directions on both to figure out what to do. Unless someone has done exactly what you are asking, it is unlikely you will get an answer. Best of Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Robert - just posting what I provide in our private thread via PubNub Support case.

For client side, I would assume the [PubNub JavaScript SDK](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) is what you need.
http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk

You might actually need the [PubNub PhoneGap SDK](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/phonegap-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk).

To add PubNub SDKs to an appery.io project, it should be documented “how to” at appery.io. I [found this blog which might be what you need](https://blog.appery.io/2011/12/using-3rd-party-javascript-library-in-your-mobile-app/).
https://blog.appery.io/2011/12/using-3rd-party-javascript-library-in-your-mobile-app/

Good luck on your coding journey.